# Why Can't I Get a Percent Calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the script that I am testing.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Account
( ProductCategory  VARCHAR(100),
  ProductSubCategory VARCHAR(100),
  TotalOrdersNAm int,
  TotalOrdersSAm int,
  TotalOrdersNAf int,
  TotalOrdersSAf int)

--Delete from Account

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('001', 'A', '2', '5', '12', '20')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('001', 'B', '5', '5', '14', '21')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('001', 'C', '1', '7', '15', '17')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('002', 'A', '6', '8', '11', '16')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('002', 'B', '3', '9', '13', '19')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('002', 'C', '2', '6', '14', '0')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('003', 'A', '8', '8', '13', '21')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('003', 'B', '2', '9', '10', '18')

INSERT INTO dbo.Account  (ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, TotalOrdersNAm, TotalOrdersSAm, TotalOrdersNAf, TotalOrdersSAf)
VALUES  ('003', 'C', '9', '0', '0', '29')

-- Select * From Account

SELECT t.ProductCategory, t.ProductSubCategory, u.Region, u.TotalOrders,
     u.TotalOrders / SUM(u.TotalOrders) OVER (PARTITION BY u.Region) as PercentageOfTotal
FROM dbo.Account t
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 'North America' as Region, TotalOrdersNAm as TotalOrders
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'South America' as Region, TotalOrdersSAm as TotalOrders
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'North Africa' as Region, TotalOrdersNAf as TotalOrders
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'South Africa' as Region, TotalOrdersNAf as TotalOrders
    ) u
```

I am on SQL Server 2017.  It seems to me, that this should work, but all I see is 0 in the 'PercentageOfTotal' field.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic, so `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  I find that the easiest way is to multiply by `1.0`:

```
 u.TotalOrders * 1.0 / SUM(u.TotalOrders) OVER (PARTITION BY u.Region) as PercentageOfTotal
```

Comment: Ahhh!  Gotta learn something new every day!!  Thanks!!